# Get members of some group

Tags: c#, active-directory, active-directory-group, activedirectorymembership

I have a LDAP address to some group, such as LDAP://CN=Users,CN=Builtin,DC=tt, DC=s, DC=LOCAL
How would I go about getting the users that belong to this group?
Originally, I thought doing this would work:

```
    DirectoryEntry group = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=Users,CN=Builtin,DC=tt, DC=s, DC=LOCAL");
        foreach (object user in group.Properties["member"])
        {
            DirectoryEntry _user = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + user);
            Console.WriteLine(_user.Properties["cn"].Value.ToString());
        }
```

However, this is not printing any of the members of the group. In fact, the foreach loop isn't even being executed, because it is not finding any members of the group. But when I look at the group in the database, it clearly has several members.

Answer (score 1):

I think the domain part is missing, even in the first DirectoryEntry object.

I use `String.Format("LDAP://{0}/{1}", _dc, distinguishedName_)` where *dc is this domain part and where distinguishedName* is your "object user" into string, in order to have something like

> LDAP://dc1.corp.domain.com/OU=Service Accounts,OU=Corp Objects,DC=corp,DC=domain,DC=com

Check it out [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/130543/how-can-i-figure-out-my-ldap-connection-string).